# Create Keystore in ElasticSearch with Password using shell script

Tags: elasticsearch, passwords, keystore

I try to create a keystore in elasticsearch using a script:
echo "$KEYSTORE_PASSWORD" | elasticsearch-keystore create -p

It is not working, as i am prompted to reenter the password again.

Can't find any solutions on the web.

Search whole elastic docs as well as the web...

```
Enter new password for the elasticsearch keystore (empty for no password): Enter same password again: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: unable to read from standard input; is standard input open and a tty attached?
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Terminal.read(Terminal.java:94)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Terminal.readSecret(Terminal.java:106)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.cli.KeyStoreAwareCommand.readPassword(KeyStoreAwareCommand.java:47)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.keystore.CreateKeyStoreCommand.execute(CreateKeyStoreCommand.java:41)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:54)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:85)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.MultiCommand.execute(MultiCommand.java:94)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:85)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:50)
        at org.elasticsearch.launcher.CliToolLauncher.main(CliToolLauncher.java:64)
```

Answer (score 0):

`echo "$KEYSTORE_PASSWORD" | path/to/elasticsearch-keystore add name_of_the_key -xf`

to create:

`echo "$KEYSTORE_PASSWORD" | path/to/elasticsearch-keystore create  -x, --stdin`

When used with the add parameter, you can pass the settings values through standard input (stdin). Separate multiple values with carriage returns or newlines